# NullPointerException en un Test "Spring Boot 2"

Tags: spring-boot

Estoy intentando realizar un test en la capa de servicio de un proyecto con Spring Boot 2, esta es mi clase;

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class PlayerServiceTest {

@InjectMocks
private PlayerServiceImpl playerService;

@Mock
private PlayerRepository playerRepository;

@Test
public void testFindNamePlayer() {
    List<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();
    Player player1 = new Player();
    Player player2 = new Player();
    players.add(player1);
    players.add(player2);

    when(playerRepository.searchPlayers("keyword")).thenReturn(players);
    assertEquals(players.size(), playerService.findByName("keyword"));
}
```

}

Pero me da una excepción "NullPointerException" porque PlayerRepository es null, alguien me podría decir como hacer para que no sea siempre "null"?
Gracias y saludos.

Esta es la implementación de PlayerServiceImpl

```
@Service
```

public class PlayerServiceImpl extends GenericServiceImpl<Player, Long>    implements PlayerServiceAPI {

```
@Autowired
private PlayerRepository playerRepository;

@Override
public JpaRepository<Player, Long> getRepository() {
    return playerRepository;
}

@Override
public Page<Player> findAll(PageRequest pageable) { 
    return playerRepository.findAll(pageable);
}

@Override
public List<String> findNamePlayer(String keyword) {
    List<String> players = playerRepository.search(keyword);
    return players;
}

@Override
public List<Player> findByName(String keyword) {
    List<Player> players = playerRepository.searchPlayers(keyword);
    return players;
}

@Override
public List<Player> findPlayersByTeam(Team team) {
    List<Player> players = playerRepository.findByTeam(team);
    return players;
}
```

}

Comment: Seria interesante poder ver el contenido de la implementacion de `playerService`. Es posible que no se haya inicializado la clase correctamente con el repositorio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que la anotación `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` no inicia el contexto de spring, por eso se produce la excepción de `NullPointerException` porque al no haber contexto de Spring no se puede utilizar ninguna de sus funciones.

Si utilizas Spring 2.0.x con Junit4 debes anotar los Mock con sus correspondientes anotaciones de spring, ademas de utilizar las siguientes anotaciones en tus clases de test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
```

Si utilizas Spring 2.1.x que por defecto tiene Junit5 solo necesitas una anotación:

```
@SpringBootTest
```